# How many bits are encoded at the horizon of a 1 km radius black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

As I understand it, all information from the matter creating the black hole is encoded on the event horizon. If there are variables I am ignorant of please include them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) $S$ (measured in J/K) from physics
and the entropy $H$ (measured in bits) from [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).
$$e^{S/k}=2^H$$
or
$$\frac{S}{k}=H\ln 2$$
where $k$ is [Boltzmann's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant).
According to Bekenstein/Hawking the [entropy of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#Overview) is
$$S=k\frac{A}{4\ell_P^2}$$
where $A$ is the surface area of the event horizon
and $\ell_P=\sqrt{\frac{G\hbar}{c^3}}=1.6\cdot 10^{-35}\text{m}$ is the [Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_length).
The surface area is $A=4\pi R^2$ where $R=1\text{ km}$ is the radius of the black hole.
Pulling all the above together you get the entropy in bits
$$H=\frac{\pi}{\ln 2}\frac{R^2}{\ell_P^2}\approx 10^{76}$$

Comment: “*where =1 km is the radius of the black hole*” - The radius of a black hole is lightlike and is measured in seconds, not in meters. The spacelike part of the black hole radius is zero meters.

Comment: That is assuming there is no mechanism to halt the collapse of matter in a BH.